Frontend Advice: Integrating 3D Beveling in Pie Chart NEXT.js project
So I'm currently working on a project where I need to create pie charts that dynamically takes data from a JSON array. I've found several React modules for this functionality, so that part seems easy right, but my manager has a specific requirement that I cant seem to get right. He wants the pie chart to have a 3D beveling effect, similar to what you might see in PowerPoint presentations. [see image link as an example] Making this 3D beveling is driving me nuts cause I just can't get it the way he wants it.
I was wondering if anyone here has experience or insights into how I could implement such a feature? Are there any libraries or techniques specifically tailored for this, like beveling, to charts created in React?
Any advice, guidance, or even alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
Example pie chart
I have looked into three.js no luck with a solution & I have tried
ResponsivePie from from "@nivo/pie" but can't get the pie chart to look exactly the same as the angle isn't precise enough also tried
react-chartjs-2 which doesn't really have 3D effects for the pie charts
Lastly I also tried three.js with slight luck just can't really wrap my head around it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
